# How to load JSON into TableView?

Tags: json, swift

I am trying to load an exercises JSON into a table view, i have a service function that gets the data from a source as JSON, and a view controller with a table that I want to load the info into. There are no errors in the code however the table loads blank rows, the debug section shows the JSON data just fine via a print command. Im a beginner so im sure im missing a core element, but cant work it out!

api service

```
class ApiService {

static var swiftyJsonVar:JSON?

class func getExerciseData() {

    Alamofire.request("https://wger.de/api/v2/exercise/?format=json").responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
        if((responseData.result.value) != nil) {
            swiftyJsonVar = JSON(responseData.result.value!)
            print(swiftyJsonVar ?? nil)
        }

    }
}
```

View Controller

```
class ExerciseDatabaseController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var ExerciseSearchField: UISearchBar!
@IBOutlet weak var ExercisesTableView: UITableView!

var arrRes = [[String:AnyObject]]() // Array of dictionary

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let arrRes = ApiService.getExerciseData()

    if let resData = ApiService.swiftyJsonVar?["exercise"].arrayObject {
        self.arrRes = resData as! [[String:AnyObject]]
    }
    if self.arrRes.count > 0 {
        self.ExercisesTableView.reloadData()
    }

    print(arrRes)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arrRes.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    var dict = arrRes[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = dict["name"] as? String
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = dict["description"] as? String
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Your web call is asynchronous. That's your issue. When you receive data, reload the tableView. Use a closure on `getExerciseData()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be loading your JSON asynchronously, which means you should have a closure in the method that makes your alamofire call.

```
class ApiService {

class func getExerciseData(completion: @escaping ([[String: AnyObject]]) -> ()) {

  Alamofire.request("https://wger.de/api/v2/exercise/?format=json").responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
      guard let jsonResponse = responseData.result.value else {
        //possibly put some sort of protection, or what you want to do if there is not a response here
        return
      }
      //instead of creating a variable for swiftyJsonVar in this class, 
      //you want to use a completion to send the array of dictionaries to the tableview asynchronously, 
      //that way it doesn't load blank
      //I'm not super familiar with swifty json(sorry). What I normally do is below.
      let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(jsonResponse)
      guard let dictArray = swiftyJsonVar["exercise"].arrayObject as? [[String: AnyObject]] else {
        //some sort of protection here if this fails
        return
      }
      completion(dictArray)
  }
}
```

So now we have made our asynchronous call(generally you want to do this whenever you are displaying information visually from an internet call that was not already preloaded/saved somewhere in app).

Next, we want to display this information in our tableview upon tableview load.

```
    class ExerciseDatabaseController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    //these should start with lower cases(exerciseSearchField), never uppercased
    @IBOutlet weak var ExerciseSearchField: UISearchBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var ExercisesTableView: UITableView!

    var arrRes = [[String:AnyObject]]() // Array of dictionary

    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      //you said you would use these delegates up top when you created the class, so you have to set them
      ExercisesTableView.delegate = self
      ExercisesTableView.dataSource = self
      fetchData()
      // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    //this method will make the api call
    //you'll notice that if you set breakpoints, it will reach the end of the method before hitting self?.arrRes = dictArray
    //this is normal and how asynchronous calls work, look into tableview threading for a deeper explanation of why that is. It is super important to understand threading in iOS
    //once it gets data back from the API call, it will go to the main thread and tell the tableview to reload with that data

    func fetchData() {
      ApiService.getExerciseData { [weak self] (dictArray) in
        self?.arrRes = dictArray
        print(self?.arrRes)
        if self?.arrRes.count > 0 {
          DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self?.ExercisesTableView.reloadData()
          }
        }
      }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      return arrRes.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
      var dict = arrRes[indexPath.row]
      cell.textLabel?.text = dict["name"] as? String
      cell.detailTextLabel?.text = dict["description"] as? String
      return cell
    }
```

You'll see I used [weak self] above. For more of an explanation of why that is necessary with asynchronous internet calls/whenever using closures, you can read here:
http://krakendev.io/blog/weak-and-unowned-references-in-swift

There are a lot of other resources for reading about weak and strong references/parent child stuff in iOS with a quick google search. Also, pursue researching asynchronous/synchronous in iOS. Both of these topics are incredibly important to learn when beginning.

Comment: I am getting the following errors trying to use this code, however it seems correct? 1. Cannot convert value of type 'JSON' to expected argument type '[[String : AnyObject]]'  2. Reference to property 'arrRes' in closure requires explicit 'self.' to make capture semantics explicit 3. Value of optional type 'Int?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'? 4. Value of type 'ExerciseDatabaseController' has no member 'ExerciseTableView'

Comment: Fixing some stuff now, one moment.

Comment: If you look at the API call, we need to clarify that the JSON response is returning as an array of dictionaries. You'll see I added as? [[String: AnyObject]]. As long as the response is that format, that should work. If that doesn't work, make a break point and po the JSON response you get for me so I can check it out.  The arrRes thing is fairly straight forward, just add self?. before it. The compiler warning probably would have done that for you if you clicked it.  The has no member thing was because of a typo in ExercisesTableView.reload data. I wrote ExerciseTableView(forgot the s)

Comment: I think I figured out where the Int not unwrapped thing is happening, is it at self?.arrRes.count > 0 ? If it is, you can click the compiler warning and add the ! that it recommends, or type: if swiftyJsonVar.count > 0 (since self?.arrRes makes arrRes optional, but swiftyJsonVar is not an optional). We checked that swiftJsonVar wasn't optional before we sent it over in the completion. I usually don't recommend adding the ! and say that you should unwrap whenever it suggests that. In this case, using the swiftyJsonVar count should be good, since we set self?.arrRes to match it.

Comment: Sorry but im confused, i added self?. to the print(arrRes) line and it gave me a caution "Expression implicitly coerced from '[[String : AnyObject]]?' to Any" there is still the 'value of optional type' error on the following line, and i didnt copy paste your response to the s wasnt missed in my code. I dont udnerstand the point you were making about the API call section as I cant run the app to show you the JSON with these errors

Comment: using if swiftyJsonVar.count > 0  causes error "Use of unresolved identifier 'swiftyJsonVar'"

Comment: Yes, make sure you changed the variable name in the fetchData method like I did. No longer dictArray, I changed it to match your previous variable. I'm running your code on a test project. As far as the "Value of type 'ExerciseDatabaseController' has no member 'ExerciseTableView'" warning goes, the warning specifically says you are missing an s, so figure out where that is.

Comment: Ive got it down to just the 'self?.exercisesTableView.reloadData' line error of 'Expression resolves to an unused function', then its just the error on the API call still "Cannot convert value of type 'JSON' to expected argument type '[[String : AnyObject]]'". Also theres a caution of "Expression implicitly coerced from '[[String : AnyObject]]?' to Any" on the line 'print(self?.arrRes)'

Comment: Just remove the print statement. Can you post your code for me? I need to see the API call. Also, the unused function thing is my bad. Add () after reloadData. Try to follow/google these errors. I can help you by explaining code, but with simple typos and such/errors specific to your project, you just need to google the small things.

Comment: ill delete it, ive just had to go out so cant paste my code. its identical to your code above but with the stated error

Comment: I assume the JSON error has to do with swiftyJson, which I'm unfamiliar with, but I can't be sure until you screenshot or paste the line that the error is occurring on.

Comment: Should i just remove swiftyjason? will it break the method

Comment: I think swiftyJSON does some magic so that it can handle unwrapping for you, so it might not be convertible to [[String: AnyObject]] because it is trying to make life easier. Maybe try `swiftyJsonVar = JSON(jsonResponse)` and then you might have to put `completion: @escaping (JSON) -> ())` instead of `completion: @escaping ([[String: AnyObject]]) -> ())` But once again, would have to see your code to tell you for sure.

Comment: You know what, I think I see the problem. Editing my code. Check out the API method and the fetchData method changes when I'm done. Make sure all your variable names are what they should be. If you changed capitals for your tableview, make sure the outlets are hooked up correctly.

Comment: thanks ill give it a go when im home! really appreciate the help

Comment: I added the code, i have 1 error left on the line '            if self?.arrRes.count > 0 {' reading 'Value of optional type 'Int?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?\

Comment: I managed to get it to build now using the force unwrap on that optional, however not when i click the view in emulator the table is empty still and theres nothing printed in the debug

Comment: Make break points at each step of the response in the API method and print out each variable to make sure the response is what you expect. For instance, break point on guard let jsonResponse and in the debugger po print(responseData.result.value) --see what returns incorrectly and fix it. It is probably a data parsing issue at this point, which depends on the response you're getting

Answer (score 0):

Reload your tableView once the JSON data from your asynchronous request is received. So your

```
self.ExercisesTableView.reloadData()
```

will go inside

```
Alamofire.request("https://wger.de/api/v2/exercise/?format=json").responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
    if((responseData.result.value) != nil) {
        swiftyJsonVar = JSON(responseData.result.value!)
        print(swiftyJsonVar ?? nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: But if i put it inside the Alamofire request then itll be in a different scope and dont see the ExercisesTableView to be able to reload it?

Comment: Why are you making a request in a different place?

Comment: because for expandability of the codebase you dont want to be putting your services inside viewcontrollers, see Phil Hudsons response above